# FileLoadException: Moq and Moq.resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, moq, autofixture

I've an issue while running unit tests on the build server in one specific project using Moq and AutoFixture.AutoMoq.
This is the error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=4.1.1308.2120, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or one of its dependencies. The located 
assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoMoq.MockPostprocessor.Create(Object 
request, ISpecimenContext context)
```

The project is build on .NET 4.5.1 and uses the following nuget packages (these versions are also used in the entire solution):

```
<package id="AutoFixture" version="3.40.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" version="3.40.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Moq" version="4.2.1510.2205" targetFramework="net451" />
```

This is one of the failing tests (using xunit 2.0):

```
[Fact]
public void SutIsIMessageConverterService()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var sut = fixture.Create<XmlValidationConverterService>();
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IMessageConverterService>(sut);
}
```

This project has an assembly binding redirect (but to no avail):

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1510.2205" newVersion="4.2.1510.2205" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Using `FUSLOGVW.exe` on the build server I found some more information (at first I assumed Moq didn't have any dependencies):

```
LOG: DisplayName = Moq.resources, Version=4.2.1510.2205, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/ProjectName.Tests
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Users\BuildServerUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\ddf02945-045c-408c-a648-ec5325032f0a
LOG: AppName = ddf02945-045c-408c-a648-ec5325032f0a
Calling assembly : Moq, Version=4.2.1510.2205, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920.
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\ProjectName.Tests.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Moq.resources, Version=4.2.1510.2205, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProjectName.Tests/en-US/Moq.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProjectName.Tests/en-US/Moq.resources/Moq.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProjectName.Tests/en-US/Moq.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProjectName.Tests/en-US/Moq.resources/Moq.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

So `Moq` depends on `Moq.resources` and it cannot be found.

Does anyone know why it's looking for this (what is it?) and how I could fix this?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or vNext build?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT TFS 2013 and a XAML build template.

Comment: AutoFixture version 3.40.1 is not available anymore. For all products new versions have been made available. Consider an upgrade.

Comment: As @JeroenHeier so keenly observes, AutoFixture 3.40.1 has been delisted, as there were problems with it. IIRC, I forgot to sign it with a strong name. That could explain what looks like an assembly load problem. Please try with a published version of AutoFixture.

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution in [this](http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/11/27/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-NuGet-Assembly-Redirects.aspx) blog:

- From any .config file, remove the  element and its child elements.
- Open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. This can be done from the View | Other Windows | Package Manager Console menu.
- Type this one, magical command that solves it all: `Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect`.

Comment: As mentioned, I have a binding redirect (I even used the command you're suggesting). But this does not work. When requesting the Moq.resources file (by Moq itself) this does not seem to come in to action.

Comment: Check the version history of AutoFixture with Auto Mocking using Moq at website https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq/, it's true that 3.40.1 is not available, you need upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been banging my head on the desk all morning, but the fix was to add the binding redirect to the config file. It seems that the AutoMoqCustomization depends on an older version of Moq, which is not referenced correctly in the package dependencies. By applying this redirect you work around the requirement.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name=\"Moq\" publicKeyToken=\"69f491c39445e920\" culture=\"neutral\" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion=\"0.0.0.0-4.2.1510.2205\" newVersion=\"4.2.1510.2205\" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```